# Knockout js: I get this error when adding subitem into an item. Error: "Cannot call method 'push' of null"

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmzcR/8/). Try to add a subgoal under "Competancy Goal - Sub goal". Nothing will be added. Any Suggestions are welcom.

**Javascript** (ViewModel and initial data)

```
var initialData;

    var data = [{
        "GoalId": 0,
        "GoalTitle": "Competancy Goal",
        "lstSubGoals": [{ "GoalId": 0, "GoalTitle": "Competancy Goal - Sub goal", "lstSubGoals": null }]
        },
        {
            "GoalId": 0,
            "GoalTitle": "Strategy Goal",
            "lstSubGoals": null
        }];
        initialData = data;
        //viewModel.goalCollection(data);

        //ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("tablebody"));

        var GoalsModel = function (goals) {
            var self = this;

            self.goals = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(goals, function (goal) {
                return {
                    GoalTitle: goal.GoalTitle,
                    Weightage: goal.Weightage,
                    StartDate: goal.StartDate,
                    EndDate: goal.EndDate,
                    Status: goal.Status,
                    editing: ko.observable(false),
                    lstSubGoals: ko.observableArray(goal.lstSubGoals)
                };
            }));

            self.addGoal = function () {
                self.goals.push({
                    GoalTitle: "",
                    Weightage: "",
                    StartDate: "",
                    EndDate: "",
                    Status: "",
                    lstSubGoals: ko.observableArray(),
                    editing: ko.observable(false)
                });
            };

            self.removeGoal = function (goal) {
                self.goals.remove(goal);
            };

            self.editGoal = function (goal) {
                self.goals.editing = ko.observable(true);
            };

            self.addSubgoal = function (goal) {
                goal.lstSubGoals.push({
                    GoalTitle: "",
                    Weightage: "",
                    StartDate: "",
                    EndDate: "",
                    Status: "",
                    lstSubGoals: ko.observableArray(),
                    editing: ko.observable(false)
                });
            };

            self.removeSubgoal = function (subgoal) {
                $.each(self.goals(), function () { this.lstSubGoals.remove(subgoal) })
            };

            self.save = function () {
                self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.goals), null, 2));

                var finalresult = JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.goals), null, 2);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/performance/assigngoal',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: finalresult,
                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Failed");
                    }
                });
            };

            self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new GoalsModel(initialData));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="goaldetailsdiv" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="divtableheader data" style="width: 25%;">Goal</div>

            <div class="divtableheader data" style="width: 15%;">Actions</div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="body" style="text-align: left;">
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'goals_template', foreach: $data.goals }" id="tablebody">

            </div>
            <script type="text/html" id="goals_template">
            <div class="category_header">
                <div>
                        <div style="float: left; width: 25%; text-align: left;" class="divtablebody data">
                            <span data-bind="text: GoalTitle"></span>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: GoalTitle" />
                        </div>

                        <div style="float: left; width: 15%;" class="divtablebody data">
                            <button data-bind='click: $root.addSubgoal'>Add</button>
                            <button data-bind='click: $root.removeGoal'>Del</button>
                            <button data-bind='click: $root.editGoal'>Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>   
               <div data-bind='template: { name: "goals_template", foreach: $data.lstSubGoals }'>
                </div>
            </div> 
            </script>
        </div>
        <button data-bind='click: save, enable: goals().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>

        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Check goal.lstSubGoals, seems it is null. And why goal, maybe self?

Comment: In this case you shold use self.goals, instead goals.

Comment: Show your complete viewModel, please.

Comment: @JohnEarles Sorry john. I did not understand your comment. Can you please tell clearly.

Comment: Okay... I've figured it out. You were trying to initialize an observable array with another observable array (which is a function). Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmzcR/7/

Comment: Here is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jmzcR/8/

Comment: i think your 'Competancy Goal - Sub goal' is an 'goal' model that why it doesn't have 'lstSubGoals' observablearray.